# Order of onclick and onselect Javascript events

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, onselect

When a user clicks on a select control to select an option, do both the `onclick` and `onselect` events fire?  If so, in what order?  Is it browser-dependent?

Comment: OK... I was thinking of onchange, not onselect (and I had onchange in my code).  I have done a little testing and have found that in Firefox, onchange precedes onclick, but both fire.  Opera behaves the same way.  In Chrome, onclick never seems to fire at all, but onchange does.  I'm on Linux, so I'll have to get to IE to test its behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The `select` event does not do what you think it does.  It fires when you select text within a textbox or textarea.  The events that fire when you click on a select element are:

1. mousedown
2. focus (if the select element did not already have focus)
3. mouseup
4. click

When you change the selected value by clicking on an item in the select list, the `change` event is fired.  In IE, this event is also fired every time you change the highlighted item with the keyboard.  In Firefox and Chrome, you have to hit the 'enter' key to trigger `change`.

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken about the event I was using -- I was using onchange, not onselect.  Nevertheless, this is helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

Should be fairly easy to test:

```
<select onclick="alert('click');" onselect="alert('select');"><option>A</option><option>B</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

- mousedown
- mouseup
- click
- select

But I'm not sure if nonstandard browsers (IE) always conform to this. If in doubt, test it with a bunch of event listeners.